# C# Generic Algorithm constraining parameter to number

Tags: c#, constraints, selection, generic-programming

I am writing a generic [roulette selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection). Normally, `property` is a primitive numeric type that can be used in summation of each element's "score".

However, since the implementation is intended to be generic and there is no way to constrain the type of the property to be a numeric primitive directly, I have no clear way to sum the values and select proportionally by the value of `property`.

In the below code, you will notice that I am trying to add the property's value to `sum` and `rouletteSum`. This code produces errors, since `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` returns an object that I cannot cast to a primitive numeric type without essentially breaking the genericness of the implementation.

**What approach can I take to assure genericness of the algorithm while still being able to proportionally compare and select from the values of the provided `property`?**

One consideration is to constrain `P` to `IConvertible`, but I would imagine that would result in some ugly typecasting when supplying primitives in the `property` parameter.

```
public class RouletteSelectionFunction : ISelectionFunction
{
  public string Name => "Roulette";

  public T Select<T, P>( IEnumerable<T> elements, Expression<Func<T, P>> property )
    where T : class
  {
    var prop = ( PropertyInfo ) ( ( MemberExpression ) property.Body ).Member;

    // Sum all fitnesses and normalize negatives
    // by shifting range to minimum of 0
    double sum = 0.0;
    double lowest = 0.0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < elements.Count(); i++ )
    {
      var value = prop.GetValue( elements.ElementAt( i ) );
      sum += value;
      if ( value < lowest )
        lowest = value;
    }
    lowest = Math.Abs( lowest );
    sum += lowest * elements.Count();

    // Roll roulette and select victor
    double rouletteSum = 0;
    double random = RandomGen.NextDouble() * sum; //RandomGen wraps Random() class and NextDouble() returns number between 0 and 1
    for( var i = 0; i < elements.Count(); i++ )
    {
      rouletteSum += prop.GetValue( elements.ElementAt( i ) );
      if ( random <= rouletteSum )
        return elements.ElementAt( i );
    }

    throw new SelectionFailedException( "Roulette Selection could not determine victor" );
  }
}

// Call via:
// RouletteSelectionFunction.Select( elements, x => x.Score )
```

Comment: You can't really do this I'm afraid. Note even the Linq `Sum` methods get around this by having overloads for each numeric type.

Comment: I think making generic is over complicating something so simple. I would simply make it fixed using `double` or even `decimal` to ensure it can take every single numeric types you throw at it.

Comment: You can get close by using Marc Gravell's [Generic Operators](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) class.  However, be aware that this will not provide compile-time checking.  I still recommend using the, "add an overload for every numeric type" approach in any public-facing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What approach can I take to assure genericness of the algorithm while still being able to proportionally compare and select from the values of the provided property?

You don't, at least not easily.  C# has never provided a generic type system suitable for abstractions over arithmetic.

There have been many proposals over the years. For example, you could imagine allowing static members in interfaces, and then you could say `where T : IAddable<T>`, where `IAddable<T>` is an interface that promises that there is an `public static T operator +(T, T)` on `T`.

You could also explicitly pass in a `Func<T, T, T>` that implements your sum, and so on.

But the problem you face is essentially that you wish to abuse generics in order to form specializations that are not actually **generic**.  We think of generics as being something like `List<T>` where you really, truly can make a list of *any type whatsoever*.  Is your code actually generic? It sounds like it could be made to work by simply saying that sums sum to `double`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have decided to force the given property to be of type `double`; something I didn't consider when developing but something that would essentially provide the behavior I was looking for.